# Necessarily follows $\varphi$ is a morphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $C$ be a smooth curve in $\mathbb{P}^2(\Omega)$, thought of as a Zariski closed subset. Let $\ell$ be a line in $\mathbb{P}^2(\Omega)$, and suppose that $\ell$ is **not** tangent to $C$ at any point.

If $P$ is a point of $C$, let $t_P$ denote the tangent line to $C$ at $P$. Define a map $f: C \to \ell$ via$$P \mapsto \text{the unique point of intersection of }t_P \text{ and }\ell.$$Does it follow that $\varphi$ is a morphism?

Comment: Does it follow from what? Are you asking if it is true that it is a morphism?

Comment: If that is the case, I suggest you write things down in coordinates and see for yourself!